# How to click a button based on a linked id value

Tags: ruby, forms, watir-webdriver

At its most basic, when a new item is added to a library it sets an id against the item. I now want to amend the item after being added but I can't figure out (after consulting Google etc) how to click a button linked with the id in question. The HTML code for the block where the id in question is located is:

```
<form action method="get" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 0; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 5px">
  <input type="hidden" name="module" value="image" id="module">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="amend">
  <input type="hidden" name="imageHeadingID" value="118">
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Amend" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
</form>
```

I'm attempting to call the "submitButton" button where the value is "118" (in the imageHeadingID").

Comment: I don't understand your question. The value of "submitButton" is "Amend" not "118".

Comment: Assuming you want to click the button named `submitButton`:
    ```b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.button(:name => 'submitButton').click```

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise my question was not clear. Each time an entry is created it is assigned an id and in the example I'm working with I've created an item and it has been assigned a value of 118 and has both an amend and delete button linked to it as each entry has its onw delete and amend buttons.  In this instance I want to click the amend button for the item with the id of 118.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting your comments correctly, its sounds like you want to:

1. Find the "item" (which is a form element) that has the "value" (which is on the hidden element) with value "118".
2. For that "item", click "Amend" (which is a input/submit element)

This can be done with:

```
form_element = browser.hidden(:name => 'imageHeadingID', :value => '118').parent
amend_element = form_element.button(:value => 'Amend')
amend_element.click
```